# Is kotlin both functional and procedural?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

Apart from object oriented can it support procedural and functional programming styles?

I want to develop an android app using Android Studio so I could explore various programming styles kotlin has to offer which would really help me explore this new language.

Thanks for taking your time read/answer this question and sorry if I sound noob as I'm a beginner to the world of programming!

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html

Answer (score 3):

From [Kotlin FAQ](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/faq.html#is-kotlin-an-object-oriented-language-or-a-functional-one):

> **Is Kotlin an object-oriented language or a functional one?**
>
> Kotlin has both object-oriented and functional constructs. You can use it in both OO and FP styles, or mix elements of the two. With first-class support for features such as higher-order functions, function types and lambdas, Kotlin is a great choice if you’re doing or exploring functional programming.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Also any idea how do I implement procedural programming?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly you want to achieve. For an overview of the Kotlin language features, see the language reference. The feature that is typical for procedural style is [top-level-declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#packages).

Comment: Actually I'm trying to implement procedural, functional and object oriented paradigms

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree that the question is a little confusing. Here is what I'm seeing as I study Kotlin in Android:

- The vast majority of actions appear to be triggered by listeners
- The listeners are (usually) contained within classes and the majority of things are done using classes (OOP)
- There are a lot of functions that aren't contained within classes and they get called frequently (Procedural)
- There is an aversion to using variables that are outside the scope of a given function or class, trying to remain true to a functional approach

Other than that, I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

1. Most anything you can do with Java (OO, Proc) is possible with Kotlin.
2. Kotlin supports High-Order, Lambdas and Closures, so while it might not be considered a functional language in a strict sense, you can use a lot of functional concepts to get your coding done. See Higher-Order Functions ([https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html](http://here))and Lambdas in the Kotlin doc.